# What´s the name of this Minecraft map plugin or mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mod-identification

I saw this on a video:

[image: screenshot]

And I wanted to do this on my *Minecraft* map! Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's called Dynmap. For Bukkit: https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/dynmap, for Forge: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/dynmapforge. There are instructions on how to install it on both project pages.